Why vendor.css is not added during gulp tasks?
I am expecting vendor.css and main.css to be attached during all my gulp operations in my <head> ( gulp dev for development, gulp prod for production ready version ), however only main.css is added.
I have verified that the path is correct, I also looked in my old configurations where it is the same, but for some reason that I can not comprehend this is not working as expected. I also tried removing the bower:css part with no luck, other parts are builded without any issue at all, like this part
    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

or the part right before </body>
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/glidejs/dist/glide.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

app structure:
root/
|-- app/|   
|-- .index.html
|   |-- styles/
|   |-- scripts/
|   |-- fonts/
|   |-- images/
|-- dist/
|-- .tmp/
|-- node_modules
|-- bower_components
|-- package.json
|-- gulpfile.babel.js
|-- bower.json

<head> of app/index.html:
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>--</title>

    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/glidejs/dist/css/glide.core.min.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </head>

<head> in .tmp/index.html ( during 'gulp dev' ) and of dist/index.html ( 'gulp prod' ):
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>--</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>

Package.json:
{
  "name": "--",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "--",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.2",
    "delete": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^1.1.3",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^9.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^2.0.8",
    "gulp-notify": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^10.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-size": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-useref": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-wiredep": "^1.2.0",
    "imagemin": "7.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "sass": "^1.75.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.23.7",
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-html-partial": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  },
  "bower": {
    "directory": "bower_components"
  }

Gulpfile.babel.js:
const { watch, src, dest, series, parallel } = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
  babel = require('gulp-babel'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  del = require('delete'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
  $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    debug: 1,
    scope: ['devDependencies']
  }),
  notify = require('gulp-notify'),
  postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
  autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
  gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
  htmlPartial = require('gulp-html-partial');


function reload(done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
}

export const clean = () => del(['.tmp', 'dist']);

function wiredep(e) {
  src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.wiredep({
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
    }))
        .pipe(dest('app/styles'));
    return src('app/*.html')
        .pipe($.wiredep({
            ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./,
            bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
            directory: 'bower_components'
        }))
        .pipe(dest('app'))
}

function html() {
  return src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlPartial({ basePath: 'app/partials/' }))
    .pipe($.useref({
      searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']
    }))
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssnano()))
    // .pipe($.if('*.html', $.htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true })))
    .pipe(dest('.tmp'))
    .pipe(dest('dist'))
}

function styles() {
  const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
  return src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
    // .pipe(cssnano())
    // .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    // .pipe(reload)
}

function scripts() {
  return src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
    // .pipe($.plumber())
    // .pipe($.babel())
    // .pipe(dest('.tmp/scripts'))
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    // .pipe(uglify())
    // .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(dest('dist/scripts'))
    // .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function images() {
  return src(
      'app/images/**/*.{png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,webp,WEBP,gif,GIF,bmp,BMP}',
      { encoding: false }
    )
    .pipe($.plumber())
    // .pipe($.cache(imagemin({
    //   encoding: false
    // })))
    //   optimizationLevel: 3,
    //   progressive: true,
    //   interlaced: true
    // })))
    // .on('error', function(err) {
      //   console.log(err);
      //   this.end();
      // })
    // .pipe(imagemin({ verbose: true }))
    .pipe(dest('dist/images'))
}

function fonts() {
  return src(
    'app/fonts/**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}',
    { encoding: false }
  )
    .pipe(dest('dist/fonts'))
}

function serve() {
  browserSync.init({
    browser: 'google chrome canary',
        notify: true,
        port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
      routes: {
                '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
            }
    }
  });

  watch('.tmp', reload);
  watch('app/**/*.html', series(html, reload));
  watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', series(scripts, reload));
  watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', series(styles, reload));
  watch('app/fonts/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}', series(fonts, reload));
}

exports.wiredep = wiredep;
exports.prod = series(clean, parallel(html, styles, scripts, images, fonts));
exports.dev = series(clean, parallel(html, styles, scripts), serve);

bower.json:
{
  "name": "--",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "authors": [
    "-- -- <--@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "glidejs": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      ]
    },
    "glidejs": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/glide.core.min.css",
        "dist/css/glide.core.map.min.css",
        "dist/glide.min.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}

I have tried to google, gpt, looked at other configurations, updating packages, tried multiple times gulp clean, gulp prod and even gulp wiredep, but it just doesn't work.
Thank you for any assistance or advice you can provide!
